# Installed Go, but command go not found. Does work on one terminal linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

I installed go on linux yesterday. It worked fine and downloaded some tools and they worked also. I left the terminal open and when I came back today go stopped working... In the left terminal go works and does everything... But when I open another terminal and type go it said "command go not found" (see screenshot).
Can anyone help me please? I don't know what I did wrong or what went wrong...

[Go works on the left terminal, not right...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIwmS.png)

Comment: I believe you need to add Go to the `.bashrc` path. Are you using the bash shell or something else?

Comment: I installed it with this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-on-ubuntu-18-04 .

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: It sounds like you either didn't update your PATH in your .bashrc (or equivalent), or your second terminal hasn't executed that after the change.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you installed this version of Go? According to the instructions it will be installed in `/usr/local/go`, and you have to add it to your PATH manually as shown in the instructions. It might be easier to install the package for your distribution as recommended by your system: `apt install ...` This will normally set up everything so that it will "just work". BTW: It is not recommended to permanently work as root. I suggest to use `sudo` only when necessary.

Comment: The digital ocean tutorial is deprecated: don't use GOPATH anymore. Refer to the official documentation

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Add the `export` command you ran to the `$HOME/.bashrc` file (preferably at the end).

---

When you installed `go` you probably ran the `export` command to add the location of `go` binaries to the `PATH` variable. But here's the thing. The `PATH` variable is, effectively, reset to the previous value when you open the new terminal. To make it permanent you need to add the command to your shell's `rc` file.

### What's an `rc` file?

When you open the terminal it uses a `rc` (short for run commands) file and runs the commands in this file. The name of the file depends on the shell you are using.
If you are using `bash`, the name would be `.bashrc`. If you are using `zsh`, the name would be `.zshrc`.

You can run `echo $PATH` in both the terminals and see the `PATH` variable in which `go` runs would have the location of `go` binaries and the other wouldn't.

So to make this permanent, add the `export PATH=$PATH:{PATH_GO_BINARIES}` to the `rc` file. And, then, whenever a new terminal is opened, the `PATH` variable would be updated to contain the location of `go` binaries.